# Inheritance af list and record fails even though the classes have the same generic types

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance

My goal is to have several similar lists using the same code (so I do not have to write a LoadFromString() and LoadFromXML() multiple times.

I made a TKeyValueList 
(and a 
    TKeyIntValueList = class(TKeyValueList

```
TKeyValueItem<T> = class(TLockObject)

protected
  FKey   : T;
  FValue : Variant;
  ....... etc

TKeyValueList<T> = class(TLockObject)

protected
  FList : TList<TKeyValueItem<T>>;
  ------ etc
```

That works fine....

But when I want to make a list of lists to hold values from DB records sent over TCP/IP (with my own "RESTFUL" protocol) it fails.

Base classes :

```
TDBRecord<IDT, FieldIDT> = class(TKeyValueList<FieldIDT> );
// Any ID type (i.e. Primary key from DB kan be int/string etc)
// Any type of field identifier, e.g. string for field name or my own 
// TCommDataType (enumeration like cdtTextID....)
```

The base list is defined as

```
TDBRecordList<IDT, FieldIDT> = class(TList<TDBRecord<IDT, FieldIDT>)
```

Then I defined a generic descendant to hold records from the DB with an int primary key, e.g SQL Server "t_TextID int identity primary key not null" to avoid having to include that in my current project where all PKs er int.

```
TDBIntIDRecord<FieldIDT> = class(TDBRecord<Integer, FieldIDT>);

TDBIntIDRecordList<FieldIDT, T : TDBIntIDRecord<FieldIDT>> = class(TDBRecordList<Integer, FieldIDT, T>);
```

To specialize this and avoid having to specify the type of the field name (which is an enum) I made this :

```
TDBCommTypeIDRecord = class(TDBIntIDRecord<TCommDataType>);

TDBCommTypeIDList = class(TDBIntIDRecordList<TCommDataType>)
```

When I try to call a method with a single TDBRecord, i.e. a TDBCommTypeIDRecord with an item of the list (TDBCommTypeIDList[StringGridItems.Selected]) I get a compiler error :

> TDBRecord is not compatible with TDBCommTypeIDRecord.

According to the documentation of generics (and Marco Cantú) generics are not tied to having the exact same type name, but rather having the same types.

So why is that part not working?????

The I tried to solve it (i.e. circumvent the issue) by  :

```
///////////////

TDBRecord<IDT, FieldIDT> = class(TKeyValueList<FieldIDT> );

TDBRecordList<IDT, FieldIDT, T : TDBRecord<IDT, FieldIDT>> = class(TList<T>);


TDBIntIDRecord<FieldIDT> = class(TDBRecord<Integer, FieldIDT>);

TDBIntIDRecordList<FieldIDT, T : TDBIntIDRecord<FieldIDT>> = class(TDBRecordList<Integer, FieldIDT, T>);


///////////////
```

This gives me a compile time error saying that IDT is not compatible with FieldIDT. Well... , obviously not! 
IDT is now Integer and FieldIDT is not (later in the flow defined at TCommDataType)

But the declaration of 
- TDBRecord and
- TDBRecordList

should eliminate IDT, as I see it.

What am I doing wrong?
What have I misunderstood?

Please help......

My attempts to solve this is described in the problem.

Included code in the description of the issue. I can provide complete POC projects to illustrate the issue.

I would - based on the documentation and Marco Cantú - expect both my first and my second attempt to compile and work runtime. Instead I got the error messages described as part of the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the compiler is right and your code is not expected to compile. However it's very hard to see through all the detail. A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Thanks, But Currently I am a bit more worried about that fact that I learned that Google Play ending support of 32 bit apps. That is a major blow to my project because Delphi does not compile to Android 64 bit. I will get back if I still use Delphi and do not rewrite everything.

Comment: Which of these two issues do you want help with?

Answer (score 1):

Are TCommDataType and FieldIDT compatible?

There are several possibilities to violate compatibility, please refer to: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi)

I suggest you to try modify below line:

```
TDBCommTypeIDRecord = class(TDBIntIDRecord<TCommDataType>);
```

into:

```
TDBCommTypeIDRecord = class(TDBIntIDRecord<FieldIDT>);
```

and see if same error still exists.

Comment: Thanks, but I do believe that doing that will simply postpone the issue. Eventually I will have to make it TCommDataType. But Currently I am a bit more worried about Google Play ending support of 32 bit apps. That is a major blow to my project.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself :

```
  TDBListField<FieldIdT> = class(TObject)


    property ID    : FieldIdT read GetId;
    property Value : Variant read GetValue write SetValue;
```

................

> TDBRecord = class(TList>)
>
> ```
>  TDBRecordList<FieldIdT> = class(TList<TDBRecord<FieldIdT>>)
> ```

//---------------------------------------------------------------

// And in the unit using it :

> type
>
> TTestEnumType = (tetNone, tetID, tetName);
>
> type   //  Field ID like 0, 1, 2, 3 etc., similar to
>   TQuery.Fields[0].Value etc.   TIntIdRecordList =
>   class(TDBRecordList);
>
> TEnumIdRecordList = class(TDBRecordList);

// Actual use :

//  Field ID like tetID, eg.

> ```
> var  
>  ID         : Variant;     MyDBRecord : TDBRecord;
>
>   begin
>  MyDBRecord   := FRecordList[0];   ID           := MyDBRecord[tetID].Value;
>   end;
> ```

The only little black cloud on an otherwise clear blue sky is the need for using interfaces and Move() to make it work. And then why have generics at all????

This reminds me of my days with assembler :

> function TDBListField.IdToString() : String;  var   TypInfo
>   : PTypeInfo;   TmpInt  : Integer;   Size    : Integer;
>
> begin   try    TypInfo := PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(FieldIdT));    TmpInt 
>   := 0;
>
> case TypInfo^.Kind of
>        tkUnknown : raise Exception.Create('Whoops');
>
> ```
>  tkInteger,
>  tkInt64       : begin
>
>                   Size   := SizeOf(FieldIdT);
>                   Move(FId, TmpInt, Size);
>                   Result := IntToStr(TmpInt);
>                  end;
>
>
>  tkEnumeration : begin
> ```

.....

> class function TDBListField.IDsEqual(AA : FieldIdT; AB :
>   FieldIdT) : Boolean;  var   Cmp : IComparer;
>
> begin   Cmp := TComparer.Default;
>
> Result := Cmp.Compare(AA, AB) = 0;
>
> end;